# Techniques to get the latest responses from network requests

Tags: javascript

given is a search component which allows us to query items. For every character an API request is fired which we are awaiting on our clientside and displaying the data inside a result list. As you can imagine our backend searches for the items matching the query.

The problem is that for requests with a short query the response takes longer than for a more specific query. This may lead to unexpected behaviour, because the response of the first network request may arrives later than the response of the second network request. Therefore, the result list is showing items with the less specific query and not with the latest typed in query.

[image]

Which techniques may exists to use the response of the latest query? I thought of transporting and reading the timestamp of the request within the response.

Comment: `timestamps inside the response` - yes (if you mean timestamp of the request, not the response of course) - though, you can achieve the same without modifying server code (useful if the API isn't yours to modify) - or, another way is to "abort" the previous request when making the next request - easy to do with [browsers that support AbortController & AbortSignal](https://caniuse.com/abortcontroller)

Comment: `if you mean timestamp of the request, not the response of course` - exactly, I edited the last sentence for clarificaton.

Comment: would you prefer the timestamp method, or aborting any inflight fetch when you make the new fetch?

Comment: I think aborting is the way to go, cause we may use the api somewhere else

Comment: then if you use browsers `fetch` it's easy to add [AbortController & AbortSignal](https://caniuse.com/abortcontroller)

Comment: Yea your approach with AbortController does work fine! However I'm in trouble mocking AbortController for my jest tests...

`jest.spyOn(global.AbortController.prototype, "signal").mockReturnValue("signal");`   `jest.spyOn(global.AbortController.prototype, "abort");`


throws `'get signal' called on an object that is not a valid instance of AbortController.`

Comment: Sorry, I don't do tests - all my code is guaranteed to work, no test needed (kidding)

Comment: Alright, in this case your're right :D